# Html form accessibility: is possible to change the 'next-focus-field' order?

Tags: web-applications, browser, webforms, accessibility

Sorry for the bad title, i'll try to explain as clear as i can ;)

Assume we have a form like:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="code-1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="title-1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price-1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="code-2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="title-2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price-2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Total:</td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="total" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The default browser's accessibility say that if i focus on the field `code-1` and press `<Tab>`, the focus pass to `title-1`, then to `price-1`, `code-2`, `title-2` and so on, following the table cell's order.

My goal is to change this behavior, in order to 'group' the prices fields together: focusing on `price-1` and pressing `<Tab>` should point the focus on `price-2`.

I know this can be done splitting the table like

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="code-1" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="title-1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="code-2" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="title-2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Total:</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="price-1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="price-2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="total" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

But if possible i'll like to avoid splitting the table.

Anyone know a cross-browser not-hack solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the [tabindex](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex) attribute:

```
<INPUT tabindex="1" type="text" name="field1">
<INPUT tabindex="3" type="text" name="field2">
<INPUT tabindex="2" type="submit" name="submit">
```